statement.executeUpdate() can't be used to insert multiple records in Oracle
With below code I am able to insert multiple Records in H2 Database.
But with Oracle this doesn't work.
Is there any other way to use normal SQL to INSERT multiple statements like that.
    //INSERT RECORDS
String    sql       = "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('"+name+"',+"+age+");" +
                      "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Susan'   ,20      )";
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
int       success   = statement.executeUpdate(sql);


You definitely shouldn't be passing parameters like that. Use PreparedStatement with setX "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?)"

Why not. If these values don't come from Frontend there is no danger from SQL Injection. And PreparedStatement is supposed to do the same thing => generate proper INSERT. Also this code is for learning. I am trying to understand Batch insert and I was under impression that it will create a String like taht with a lot of INSERTs. But it doesn't work with Oracle.

It's just good practice and there's no need to run the risk of quoting going wrong. Plus you won't be able to get any potential optimisation from using bind variables otherwise. Batching has a different purpose - it's for optimising writes, not for doing what is essentially running a SQL script. I would look into "how do I run a SQL script in JDBC?"

"Why not." Some drivers+servers could make use of cached parsed statements / execution plans. With concatenation, every statement is unique so no-reuse. Not a problem for small batch size but could make a big different on large enterprise systems.

Prepared statement also escapes: If you have a name with an apostrophe 'd'Isle'. You try two statements at once, a VALUES((...), (...)) would have done the trick. But PreparedStatements are just healthy. Not using them flags tools or human readers

one Statement can only hold one statement - even the use of ; at the end is/was not supported by all drivers

@user85421 While true for SQL statements, in Oracle you can also use one PL/SQL statement and that single PL/SQL statement can contain multiple SQL statements (each of which must be terminated by ; and so must the PL/SQL statement; however the / statement terminator for the PL/SQL block is forbidden). So the OP could use BEGIN INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Alice',20); INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Susan', 20); END; (but it is probably better to use a parameterised query and batch inserts).

@MT0 well, PL/SQL is not Java; and one (PL/)SQL statement, even if containing more statements, is still one statement; and the question is not using a PL/SQL Statement, but two statements -- it is the SQL client of Oracle that interprets ; as a statement separator  -- and, by the way, it was one of the older JDBC (not PL/SQL) drivers of exactly Oracle that did not accept a semi-colon at the end of a (single) statement

Use a PreparedStatement and do not include the ; terminator in the SQL statement (as it is not part of the SQL statement and is not valid syntax):
connection con.setAutoCommit(false);   
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES (?,?)"
);
ps.setString(1, "Susan");
ps.setInt(2, 20);
ps.addBatch();
ps.setString(1, "Alice");
ps.setInt(2, 21);
ps.addBatch();
int [] numInserts = ps.executeBatch();
connection.commit();

Note: In Oracle, you cannot have more than one statement in a command so trying to pass INSERT INTO t VALUES('X'); INSERT INTO t VALUES('Y') will fail with a syntax error even if the statements are individually syntactically valid (this helps to prevent SQL injection attacks). You need to either (1) send them individually as two commands or (2) wrap them in a PL/SQL block so that they become a single command. In your case, just use a batch of statements.


Is there any other way to use normal SQL to INSERT multiple statements like that.

There are multiple ways to insert multiple rows in a single statement:

Using an INSERT ALL statement:
INSERT ALL
  INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('Susan', 20)
  INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('Alice', 21)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL


Using INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...:
INSERT INTO person (name, age) 
  SELECT 'Susan', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alice', 21 FROM DUAL


Mureinik's answer shows how to use INSERT INTO with multiple VALUES clauses, which is available from Oracle 23.

Using PL/SQL to wrap multiple individual INSERTs:
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('Susan', 20);
  INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('Alice', 21);
END;



You can parameterise all of those queries by replacing 'Susan', 'Alice', 20 and 21 with ? and then pass the values as bind parameters using Java.
Note: The first three do not include a trailing ; but the PL/SQL solution would include the trailing ; to terminate the END statement (but not a trailing / as the terminator for the PL/SQL block).

MTO's answer about using batches is probably the best way to go.
Having said that, just to give a full picture about the original question:

Is there any other way to use normal SQL to INSERT multiple statements like that.

In Oracle (from version 23 and above), you can have multiple values sets with commas (,) between them:
String SQL = "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('"+name+"',+"+age+"), ('Susan', 20)";

This can, of course, be done with a PreparedStatement and bind the values instead of concatenating them:
String SQL = "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?), ('Susan', 20)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setInt(2, age);
ps.executeUpdate();

or even convert all the values to placeholders:
String SQL = "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setInt(2, age);
ps.setString(3, "Susan");
ps.setInt(4, 20);
ps.executeUpdate();


"In Oracle, you can have multiple values sets with commas (,) between them." Only from Oracle 23, before that you would need to use an INSERT ALL statement or INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT .... FROM DUAL. See this question.

@MT0 good distinction, thanks - edited that in.
